# How to make sure an Input Integer stays an Integer on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, forms

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway to my website. What I need to do is to send:

```
{ 
"api_key": "pkabcd12345", 
"currency": "USD", 
"amount": 0.2,
"method": "MOBILE_MONEY",
"provider_id": "airtel_ug", 
"account_number": "256777111000",
"merchant_reference": "12345", 
"narration": "Payment for Hosting",
"redirect_url": ""
}
```

using POST to https://api.dusupay.com/v1/collections

I have tried to send this as HTML Input form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://api.dusupay.com/v1/collections" name="frm1">
<input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="pkabcd12345" required>
<input type="number" name="amount" value='150' required>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD" required>
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="MOBILE_MONEY" required>
<input type="hidden" name="provider_id" value="airtel_ug" required>
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_reference" value="12346" required>
<input type="hidden" name="narration" value="diamond1" optional>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="" optional>
</form>
<button onclick="document.frm1.submit()">Submit</button>
```

But the application returns an error saying "Parameter 'amount' should be a float/integer".

I have also tried to post the JSON object directly through html form, something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://api.dusupay.com/v1/collections" name="frm1" >
<input value =  '{ 
"api_key": "pkabcd12345", 
"currency": "USD", 
"amount": 0.2,
"method": "MOBILE_MONEY/CARD/BANK", 
"provider_id": "airtel_ug, mtn_ug", 
"account_number": "256777111000",
"merchant_reference": "12345", 
"narration": "Payment for Hosting",
"redirect_url": ""
}' required>
</form>
<button onclick="document.frm1.submit();">Submit</button>
```

But it doesn't even pass the first check, it throws the error "Parameter 'api_key' missing".

Comment: did you test it on sandbox? [link](https://dashboard.dusupay.com/docs/#testing-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

> The type attribute specifies the type of  element to display.

Even if you set the type of input to number, the form will still submit it as a string, demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
console.log(typeof document.getElementById("yourinput").value)
```

```html
<input id="yourinput" type="number" name="amount" value='150' required>
```

Also that is not how you perform a post with json values, instead you would write your own function to do so for instance using fetch:

```
fetch("https://api.dusupay.com/v1/collections", {
    method: 'post',
    body:    JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
})
    .then(res=>res.json()) // if the answer is in json format
    .then(console.log)
```

But that's not all, it seems that you got confused and included all different types of provider and method, in your JSON body instead of just one valid for this particular request.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification on the HTML part. Is it possible to convert that input type from that string to Integer? I mean, so that when you log it on console it shows Int. For the JSON part, I don't really know much about JSON, JavaScript and JavaScript related languages gives me a lot of difficulty. I guess I need to learn more about JSON so that I can understand what you said better.

Comment: its still a string when you log it onto console